Affine parameterization
Considering a curve $x^\mu$ parameterized by parameter $u$, the tangent to the curve satisfies
\begin{equation}
\eta^\mu \nabla_\mu u =1
\label{affine}
\end{equation}
where $\eta^\mu = \frac{dx^\mu(u)}{du}$.
One way to check whether the parameter $u$ is affine or not is to check whether it takes value in the whole $(-\infty,+\infty)$ range [See, for example, General Relativity: A Geometrical Approach, by Malcolm Ludvigsen, Section 10.1, 12.1 ].
Can anyone help me to see any utilitiy of the approach though? Because starting with any metric, for example, a 2D metric $$ds^2=-r^2dt^2+dr^2,$$ any parameter $v$ choosen to parameterize the curve $x^\mu$ would trivially satisfy the above equation and will not give any information about the bound on $v$!

This is certainly not the right way to test affineness. For example, if $\tau$ is an affine parameter such that $\tau \in (-\infty,\infty)$, then $\tau^3$ is NOT affine even though $\tau^3 \in (-\infty,\infty)$ also.
